# Is it possible to see the end of the world in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape there used to be an area that was just a black wall. Is it still there and if so where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few locations in Runescape where you can walk right up to the end of the world. These locations include the eastern and southwestern areas of the desert south of Al Kharid, the southwest part of the forest hunter area, and south of Mobilising Armies.

You can find all areas that border the end of the world on the world map, where the black on the outside borders a reachable area.